# Diffrence between XAMPP 5.6 and 7.1.4

Tags: apache, xampp

I wonder why Apache still offers and promotes version 5.6 of XAMPP when they got newer versions like 7.1.4? 
As you can see [here](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/download.html)there are different PhP Versions in each Version but is legacy the only reason someone would use an older xampp version or are any other aspects that I am missing?

Comment: this isn't a question for so...

Comment: The difference is the bundled PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

Because XAMPP v5.6 offers **PHP v5.6**; XAMPP v7.1.4 comes with **PHP v7.0.18** not all developers have their environments past that version of PHP---and for legacy purposes too (for older PHP apps that have yet to migrate to the latest and greatest PHP version)

Hope this helps!

Best,

-Rush